# Installing JDK on Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, java, dpkg, jdk, oracle

i want to install jdk but it get this error :

```
 download failed Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed. 
 dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1 
 Errors were encountered while processing:  
  oracle-java7-installer  
  oracle-java8-installer
 E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

how can i  fix it ????

Comment: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-on-ubuntu-with-apt-get

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install oracle JDK 8 you should download it from [JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)
and choose jdk-{version}-linux-x64.tar.gz.